# Why kotlin == operator returns false for strings that look exactly the same?

Tags: java, string, kotlin, equals

One string comes from a file, the other one is initialized with double quotes.

The strings are identical when I inspect them during debugging and when printed out, yet the == operator and  `equals` method both return false when comparing the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started comparing the strings character by character.
This function returns the first position where the strings differ, or -1 if they are the same.

```
private fun characterCompare(lhs: String, rhs: String): Int {
    var i = 0
    while (i < lhs.length && i < rhs.length) {
        val lchar = lhs[i]
        val rchar = rhs[i]

        if (lchar != rchar) {
            return i // I set a breakpoint here to take a look at the values
        }
        i++
    }
    return if (i < lhs.length || i < rhs.length) i else -1
}
```

...and in my particular case, the problem was that the string that came from the file, contained an UTF8 byte order mark (BOM) at the beginning, which never showed up when the string was displayed.

This funcion removes the BOM if it is present:

```
private const val UTF8_BOM = "\uFEFF"
private fun removeUTF8BOM(str: String): String {
    return if (str.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
        str.substring(1)
    } else {
        str
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done for identifying your problem.  But this answer shows that the title is wrong!  If strings compare as unequal, then they _don't_ have the same value.  This answer shows one way strings can _look_ the same without having the same characters; but there are many others (such as zero-width spaces, composed/decomposed forms, and non-Latin letters that look like Latin ones). — So this answer might be better if it showed how to _identify_ such differences, as well as fix this particular one.

Comment: Thanks @gidds I edited the question and the answer.